# estimate object's height and width using lidar data

Tags: python, math, geometry, camera-calibration, lidar

I'am currently working on lidar and camera fusion for object detection, distance and size estimation. I'am struggling with the width and height estimation using lidar data ( x and y coordinates ) .
i need help with a method that makes use of all the info extracted from the lidar sensor to estimate the object's size!
NB :1- the bbox are provided by the yolov5 algorithm.
2- I have calculated the actual distance of each object inside a bbox.
height and width of the cyclist in the image attached : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbOZg.png)

Comment: post needs something tangible like data and code.

Comment: hello , i'm trying to estimate the hight and width of a detected cyclist in images same as how i managed to measure the distance using z coordinate of  lidar sensor data

Comment: i have added the image for more clarification

Comment: ok so you _have_ distance info... good! now you need a calibration for your camera. focal length is most important. given focal length and and physical distance (Z), you can turn distances in pixels on the image (X,Y) into physical distances (X,Y). do you _have_, or can you obtain, a calibration for your camera?

Comment: thank you for your replay , i do have calibration files with calibration matrices for the camera but i didn't know how to calculate the focal length

Comment: why is that info not in your post? add everything you have, everything that might be useful

Comment: i have managed to calculate the F_length, how can i estimate the width and height? will i need the sensor's width and height measurements too ?

Comment: if you find that my answer solves your question, you can mark it as the solution. please take the [tour] to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is geometry around the ["pinhole camera" model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model).

Let's first regard the unit circle.

[image: unit circle and some trig functions]

<sub>Picture from [debraborkovitz.com](https://debraborkovitz.com/2012/02/the-tangent-is-a-tangent/)</sub>

Your camera is at the origin looking at B. The object is the line BC. Let's say it is 1 meter away (O-B), and 0.5 meters tall (B-C). It spans a certain angle of the unit circle (your view). Let's call that `alpha` (or theta, doesn't matter).

- `tan(alpha) * 1.0 m = 0.5 m`
- `tan(alpha) * distance[m] = length[m]`
- `tan(alpha) = length[m] / distance[m]`

`alpha` isn't important, but `tan(alpha)` is, because it's *proportional* to the object's length. Only keep that in mind.

*Focal length* is just a *factor*, describing *image resolution*. Say `f = 1000 px`, then this object would be `500 px` tall because

```
length[px] = f[px] * tan(alpha)
           = f[px] * length[m] / distance[m]
```

Now, if lidar says the object is `5 m` away, and the image says the object is `300 px` tall/wide, you calculate

- `length[px] = f[px] * length[m] / distance[m]`
- rearrange
- `length[m] = length[px] / f[px] * distance[m]`
- `length[m] = 300px / 1000px * 5m`
- `length[m] = 1.5 m`

You need to know the focal length (in pixels) for your camera. That is either given by the manufacturer, somewhere in the documentation, or you have to calculate it. There are calibration methods available. You can also calculate it from manual measurements.

If you need to estimate it, you can just place a yard stick at a known distance, take a picture, measure its length in pixels, and use the previous equations to evaluate:

`f[px] = length[px] * distance[m] / length[m]`

If you knew the sensor's pixel pitch, let's say `1.40 µm/px`, and the true focal distance (not 35mm-equivalent), let's say `4.38 mm`, then `f[px] = 4.38 mm / (1.40 µm/px) = 3128 px`. Those values are roughly representative of smartphone cameras and some webcams.